# using jmesPath in helm chart to install kyverno policies on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes-helm, policy, jmespath

when i use command : helm install kyverno-policies ,Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: parse error at (kyverno-policies-fix/templates/default/require-network-policy.yaml:38): function "request" not defined

while the require-network-policy.yaml file :

```
{{- $name := "require-network-policy" }}
{{ if not (has $name .Values.disableDefaultTemplates) }}
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: {{ $name }}
  annotations:
    policies.kyverno.io/title: Require NetworkPolicy
    policies.kyverno.io/category: Sample
    policies.kyverno.io/minversion: 1.6.0
    kyverno.io/kyverno-version: 1.6.2
    kyverno.io/kubernetes-version: "1.23"
    policies.kyverno.io/subject: Deployment, NetworkPolicy
    policies.kyverno.io/description: >-
      NetworkPolicy is used to control Pod-to-Pod communication
      and is a good practice to ensure only authorized Pods can send/receive
      traffic. This policy checks incoming Deployments to ensure
      they have a matching, preexisting NetworkPolicy.      
spec:
  validationFailureAction: {{ .Values.validationFailureAction }}
  background: false
  rules:
  - name: require-network-policy
    match:
      any:
      - resources:
          kinds:
          - Deployment
    preconditions:
      any:
      - key: - key: {{`{{request.operation || 'BACKGROUND'}}`}}
        operator: Equals
        value: CREATE
    context:
    - name: policies_count
      apiCall:
        urlPath: "/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/{{`{{request.namespace}}`}}/networkpolicies"
        jmesPath: "items[?label_match(spec.podSelector.matchLabels, {{`{{request.object.spec.template.metadata.labels}}`}})] | length(@)"
    validate:
      message: "Every Deployment requires a matching NetworkPolicy."
      deny:
        conditions:
          any:
          - key: "{{policies_count}}"
            operator: LessThan
            value: 1
{{- end }}
```

chart.yaml file :

```
apiVersion: v2
name: fix-kyverno-policies
description: A Helm chart that provisions Kyverno including the custom rules to test
type: application
version: 0.1.3
appVersion: "0.1.4"
condition: kyverno.enabled
```